# Request for an auth token using Spring OAuth 2.0 fails with error code "500 Internal Server Error" for scope read and write

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I have configured Spring OAuth 2.0 in my application. I am requesting for access token using advanced rest client. This works and I get back a token in response when I pass scope=read or scope=write in payload.

**working request for read**
[image]

**working request for write**
[image]

But when I send read write together both in same request, It gives me an error saying "500 Internal Server Error". 
For read write request the payload I am sending is:

`grant_type=password&scope=read+write&client_id=BankingModule&client_secret=B90-388F-4EE-9758-CDA602&username=myuser&password=password`

Please help me out.